# mongoose connects only to localhost

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I always get "Listening at localhost" but the URL I put is from Mongo Atlas. And when I print the environment variable to the console I get it correctly. mongoose automatically ignores any url other than localhost.

I have tried to restart nodemon muiltiple times.

```
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL); //prints the correct url but mongoose connects to localhost
    console.log("mongo connected");
    // logEntry.collection.drop();
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

validate the connection using the below mentioned code snippet.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const expressServer = app.listen(3001);
const io = socketio(expressServer);
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://<UserName>:<Password>@democluster0.abcde.mongodb.net?retryWrites=true&w=majority');

mongoose.connection.on('open', function (ref) {
    console.log('Connected to mongo server.');

    mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, names) {
        console.log(names);
    });
})
```

Refer the below link to gain the URL for the same..

https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/tutorial/connect-to-your-cluster/

Comment: I've ran this code instead of mine and still.."Listening at localhost"

Comment: How are verifying the same ??
Could you share screenshots?

Comment: My bad, I just saw that it is connected to the correct database. and yes I saw the verifying with the database name. probably a caching issue. thank you.

Comment:  Good Learning!!